# Is the integral $\int_0^{+\infty} x^{2a-1} e^{-4x} dx$ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, gamma-function

Let $0<a<\frac12$. I am trying to understand if there exists a constant $C>0$ (possibly depending on $a$) such that integral
$$\int_0^{+\infty} x^{2a-1} e^{-4x} dx$$
is so that
$$\int_0^{+\infty} x^{2a-1} e^{-4x} dx\le C.$$

I see that there are no problems at infinity but probably there is a problem at $0$ when $a\to 0$.

I have also computed directly the integral, which returns $$-\frac{\Gamma(2a, 4x)}{4a},$$ where $\Gamma(2a, 4x)$ stands for the incomplete Gamma function.
However, I can not manage the computations to prove if it is bounded or not.

Anyone could please help me?

Comment: Your evaluation of the integral is wrong: $x$ is the integration variable, it can't appear in the result. But you are close, it's $\dfrac{\Gamma(2a)}{4^{2a}}$. You may use a change of variable to get directly the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: The gamma function is not defined at the negative integers.  So, if it were possible for $2a$ to be a negative integer, then the function would not be bounded, but as it isn't you don't have a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On $0 < x < 1$, you have $$x^{2a-1}e^{-4x} > x^{2a-1}e^{-4}.$$

Therefore,
$$\int_0^\infty x^{2a-1}e^{-4x}\,dx \geq \int_0^1x^{2a-1}e^{-4x}\,dx \geq \int_0^1x^{2a-1}e^{-4}\,dx = \frac{1}{2a}e^{-4}$$

This lower bound tends to $\infty$ as $a \to 0$, so there is no such $C$ independent of $a$.

Comment: Brian Moehring, thank you. Which is an upper bound (depending on $a$)?

Comment: @Physicsuser Cut the integral in two intervals at $x=1$. For $x<1$ the integrand is less than $x^{2a-1}$, that you can integrate. For $x>1$ the integrand is less than $e^{-4x}$, that you can integrate as well. All in all, the integral is $< \dfrac1{2a}+\dfrac{e^{-4}}4$.

Comment: For a slightly tighter lower bound: $\int_0^\infty x^{2a-1} e^{-4x} dx > \int_0^{1/4} x^{2a-1} (1-4x)\,dx = \frac{2^{-1-4a}}{a+2a^2}$.  That lower bound is also asymptotic to $\frac{1}{2a}$ as $a\to 0^+$.  Therefore, the original integral is asymptotic to $\frac{1}{2a}$ as $a\to 0^+$.

Answer (score 1):

The integral converges around $0$ if $x^{2a-1+1}>0$ that is if $2a>0\Rightarrow a>0.$ At infinity it is bounded for arbitrary $k$ as $e^{-x}$ is sufficient enough for it to make it converge. Therefore it converges for $a>0.$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\M}[1]{\left\{ \mathcal{M} #1 \right\} }$
About your computation: you don't need the incomplete Gamma, and in fact, as indicated by @Jean-Claude Arbaut, your evaluation is incorrect. The fastest way to compute this is to use the table of Mellin transforms and their properties:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{2a-1}e^{-4x}dx=\left\{ \mathcal{M} e^{-4x} \right\}(2a)=4^{-2a}\left\{\mathcal{M} e^{-x} \right\}(2a)=4^{-2a}\Gamma(2a)$$

Here we have used:

1. The definition of the Mellin transform:
   $$\M{ f(x)}(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}f(x)dx$$
2. The property
   $$\M{ f(ax) }=a^{-s}\M{f(x)}$$

proven by simple change of variables and integration by parts.

3. The fact that, by definition of the Mellin transform and Gamma function,
   $$\M{e^{-x}}=\Gamma(s)$$

Comment: You really don't need a table here. With the change of variable $u=4x$, $$\int_0^\infty x^{2a-1}e^{-4x}\;\mathrm dx=\frac14\int_0^\infty (u/4)^{2a-1}e^{-u}\;\mathrm du=\frac1{4^{2a}}\int_0^\infty u^{2a-1}e^{-u}\;\mathrm du=\frac{\Gamma(2a)}{4^{2a}}$$

Comment: Yea, you don't, but if you remember it, it is faster :)